# Use Do to evaluate an expression over two indices $i \ne j$ (over a list of tuples)?

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

I have an expression of the form:

```
expr1[i_,j_] = Sum[\[Beta][j]*\[Phi][i, j]* C[i]
```

I would like to evaluate this expression over i=1:4, j=1:4 with i!= j.

One way of doing this is to evaluate this expression over a list of tuples, say:

```
A = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}}.
```

I would like to use "Do" or something similar to "loop" over my list of tuples A. Is there a way to do this in Mathematica?
I know I can do

```
expr1 @@@ A
```

but is there a way to do this using Do ?

Comment: One possibility might be to sum over all combinations of $i$ and $j$ and then subtract out the combinations where $i=j$.  This might not be the most machine efficient approach but if you only have 4*4 combinations to look at, it won't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

You could just make the equal indices vanish:

```
Sum[Sign[Abs[i - j]] c[i] \[Phi][i, j] \[Beta][j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 
  4}]
```

or better as @Guesswhoitis. using Iverson notation concept:

```
Sum[Boole[i!=j] c[i] \[Phi][i, j] \[Beta][j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 
  4}]
```

or somewhat ridiculous:

```
mat[sym_, m_, n_] := 
 Normal@SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> sym[i, j] /; i != j, {m, n}]
cm = Array[c, 4]
be = Array[\[Beta], 4]
cm.mat[\[Phi], 4, 4].be
```

where you must match up row and column lengths.

Comment: Iverson brackets seem clearer to me for this, tho: `Boole[i != j]`. Also, since you're using `mat` for matrix products anyway, you don't really need the application of  `Normal[]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. yes much better agree will update with appropriate (attribution)

Comment: After putting in the Iverson brackets, you don't need to take signs anymore. :)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. yes...a result of laziness in copying and worse thought...have corrected now

Answer (score 1):

```
r1=Plus @@ (\[Beta][#2]*\[Phi][#1, #2]*C[#1] & @@@ A);
```

or

```
r2=expr1[i_, j_] = 
 Sum[If[i == j, 0, \[Beta][j]*\[Phi][i, j]*C[i]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 
   4}]

r1 === r2 
(*True*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pairs = ## & @@@ {#, Reverse /@ #} &@Subsets[Range[4], {2}];
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 
>     1}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}}

```
Total[β[#2] ϕ[##] C[#] & @@@ pairs]
(*or Sum[β[k[[2]]] ϕ[##&@@k] C[k[[1]]],{k,pairs}] *)
```

> ```
>     C[1] β[2] ϕ[1, 2] + C[1] β[3] ϕ[1, 3] + 
>     C[1] β[4] ϕ[1, 4] + C[2] β[1] ϕ[2, 1] + 
>     C[2] β[3] ϕ[2, 3] + C[2] β[4] ϕ[2, 4] + 
>     C[3] β[1] ϕ[3, 1] + C[3] β[2] ϕ[3, 2] + 
>     C[3] β[4] ϕ[3, 4] + C[4] β[1] ϕ[4, 1] + 
>     C[4] β[2] ϕ[4, 2] + C[4] β[3] ϕ[4, 3]
> ```

Comment: You could also use `pairs = Cases[Tuples[Range[4], 2], Except[{i_, i_}]]` (or equivalent `Select` or `DeleteCases`) instead of maybe slightly more unintuitive reversing trick.

Comment: @kirma,  you are right; I just wanted to avoid `Tuples` for cases where `i` and `j` range over a large set.